# What is "rotate 13" in "/etc/logrotate.conf" file?

Tags: logrotate

What is meant by "rotate 13" in "/etc/logrotate.conf" file? Can this be changed to "rotate 4" ?

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.conf
    # see "man logrotate" for details
    # rotate log files weekly
    weekly

    # keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
    rotate 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment is not correct.
This statement keeps 13 weeks worth of the logs.

'rotate' means that it keeps the old logfiles for as many cicles as specified. (A cycle is in your case a week)

From the documentation at https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

> rotate count
>
> Log files are rotated count times before being removed or mailed to the address specified in a mail directive. If count is 0, old versions are removed rather than rotated.

Answer (score 0):

The rotate command determines how many archived logs are returned before logrotate starts deleting the older ones.

You can read more about it [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) and [here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/).

Answer (score 0):

rotate 13 means logrotate rotate the log files till count 13, after that logrotate start to shift the files: like logfile_1 shifted to logfile_2 and  logfile_2 shifted to logfile_3 and so on. for that logrotate discard the last logfile_13 and create a new file at logfile1